# Stop RadNumericText box to convert the decimal numer to Exponential

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

How to stop RadNumericText box to convert decimal numbers to Scientific notation?

```
     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadText" Width="100" runat="server">
     <NumberFormat AllowRounding="false" DecimalDigits="15"  /></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

The issue is when I enter the data like =0.00000001 in the text box & when I again click on the same its converted to  1e-8.

Is there any way to restrict the radnumeric text to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

KeepNotRoundedValue="true"